# How to select most occurring element from each row from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have an R dataframe consisting of 40 rows and 16 columns, all factors. I want to create a 17th column, containing the most recurring element (factor) per row. I compared methods explained here on stackexchange, but as far as I know, none of these methods answered my question. Say for example I have this:

```
    CAT1    CAT2    CAT3   ...  
1   A       B       B
2   B       B       A
3   A       A       A
4   C       C       A
5   B       C       C
...
```

I want a fouth column that looks like this:

```
   COLUMN
1  B
2  B
3  A
4  C
5  C
```

It shouldn't be difficult, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table`:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "    CAT1    CAT2    CAT3  
                 1   A       B       B
                 2   B       B       A
                 3   A       A       A
                 4   C       C       A
                 5   B       C       C", header = TRUE)

find_most_frequent <- function(x) names(which.max(table(x)))
DF$COLUMN <- apply(DF, 1, find_most_frequent)
#  CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 COLUMN
#1    A    B    B      B
#2    B    B    A      B
#3    A    A    A      A
#4    C    C    A      C
#5    B    C    C      C
```

In case of ties this returns the value that comes first after sorting. Read `help("Comparison")` for important details regarding sorting of characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Not sure how, but it works!

Comment: Simply dissect the statement and test  to see how it works: `table(unlist(DF[1,])); which.max(table(unlist(DF[1,])))`

Answer (score 1):

Another idea using `table`,

```
df$new <- apply(df, 1, function(i)names(sort(-table(i)))[1])
df
#  CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 new
#1    A    B    B   B
#2    B    B    A   B
#3    A    A    A   A
#4    C    C    A   C
#5    B    C    C   C
```

Comment: Partial sorting should be sufficient.

Comment: I m not aware of that. I Will give it a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses the `tabulate` function:

```
df$mostCommon <- apply(df, 1, function(i) {
  i <- as.factor(i)
  levels(i)[which.max(tabulate(i))]})
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="CAT1    CAT2    CAT3
A       B       B
B       B       A
A       A       A
C       C       A
B       C       C")
```

If there are ties, then the first one (A over B, B over C) will be chosen.